# Aligning equations in article class

Tags: align

I am writing a paper in `article` class. It contains a few equations that I am trying to align. I want the alignment to look like this:

[image]

I am having trouble centering the texts "eq.(1)" and "eq.(2)" right below s.t. and aligning all equations to the left. Will appreciate any advice. I attach my MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\max_{K_{t+1}^{j}, I_{t}^{j}, h_{t}^{j}, x_{t}^{j}, l_{it}^{j}} & \mathbb{E}_{0}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \prod_{m=0}^{t} q_{m}\pi_{t}^{j} \qquad q_{m} = \beta^{m}\frac{U_{C_{m}}}{U_{C_{m-1}}} \\
& s.t. \\
& \text{eq.(1)}, \\
& \text{eq.(2)},
\end{align*} 
\begin{equation}
\pi_{t}^{j} = A_{t}F\left(K_{t}^{j}, h_{t}^{j}\right) - w_{t}h_{t}^{j} - I_{t}^{j} + x_{t}^{j} - \int_{0}^{1}R_{it-1}l_{it-1}^{j} + \Omega_{t}^{j}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
K_{t+1}^{j} = I_{t}^{j} + \left(1 - \delta\right)K_{t}^{j}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1}l_{it}^{j}\mathrm{d}i = \phi I_{t}^{j} \quad \phi \leq 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\ln\left(A_{t+1}\right) = \rho \ln\left(A_{t}\right) + \epsilon_{t}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}`.

Comment: @Clara Thanks. It aligns equations to the left so it solves the second part of my question. Do you know how I can center the texts "eq.(1)" and "eq.(2)" below s.t.?

Comment: No need `\text` in equation, you can just put the text out of equation. And use `center` enviroment.

Comment: `center` environment will center the text in the middle of the line. I need to 'center' it right below 's.t.', as in the screenshot.